# The status of unobservable quantum mechanical predictions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

Orthodox quantum mechanics intrinsically requires an observer - since the only connection from the mathematical formalism to physical reality is through the measurement axiom (probability of observing something given via Born rule, etc.). Otherwise, no assumptions about physical reality are made, and QM enables (maybe even encourages -- e.g. Bell's theorem) one to take a non-realist position, namely that there exists no independent (of observation) reality out there.

Given such a position though, what meaning do claims about the distance future such as "The universe will end in a heat death" have? By their very premise, there can be no possible observers left at that time - but then, who is doing the measuring? Or, put differently, if there is no possible way to observe a prediction, then according to a non-realist view such a prediction should be meaningless.

Are we then to assume that all such predictions about the distant future when there will be no observers left, are made in a realist context? But even then, strictly speaking, if there is no one left to verify the prediction, it is untestable - and so in some sense epistemologically meaningless (and is in the same equivalence class as claiming, say, that "the Earth is supported by a giant invisible turtle").

Comment: *Orthodox quantum mechanics intrinsically requires an observer* - I don't think this is necessarily true. Your favoured interpretation of QM may require an observer to collapse superpositions, but this is not true of all interpretations.

Comment: In QM an observer can be almost everything not just a person. Anyway, most of the things science describes are not directly observed, so your deduction is wrong.

Comment: The universe itself is doing the measuring. As @jinawee pointed out in the response above, decoherence can happen (and usually does - I am not aware of any experiment allowing us to observe it as it happens, yet) way before an actual person does the measuring. As such, other boson, fermions, atoms, or "almost everything" in the universe can, and does, the "observation", long before and after us humans.

Comment: For a good (IMO) explanation of QM and conscious observers, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48383/connection-between-quantum-physics-and-consciousness?rq=1

Comment: @JohnRennie : Right, but I was specifically talking about  non realist interpretations - which do require a subjective observer to collapse the superpositions.

Comment: @jinawee : 1. I never claimed an observer has to be a person. 2. Direct/indirect observation isn't relevant to my question - theoretical entities of scientific theories must always be (indirectly) observable through some direct experiment/observation. [E.g. we don't observe an electron, however we do observe the readings on an apparatus registering it or its effects].

Comment: @user1459524: Decoherence doesn't solve the measurement problem - even after decoherence occurs the system is still in a linear superposition of eigenstates. Which one of the associated eigenvalues is going to *actually* be observed by an observer (e.g. via an apparatus reading, etc.) in an experiment is still not predicted by decoherence. So my question still stands : in an non-realist interpretation, if there is no one to actually observe any actual/particular result of a measurement - then what exactly does the theory predict - what meaning is to be given to the prediction claim?

Comment: @user1459524: And even in a realist interpretation, where an actual value is ascribed to a theoretical construct (such as the $Q$ position in Bohm's interpretation), there is again no one to observe it - so even here the claim is not testable.

Comment: You are arguing in circles, then. If "there exists no independent (of observation) reality out there" already contains the answer in its assumption. Which is one if the reasons, btw, why I don't subscribe to this and similar views.

Comment: @user1459524 : But I wasn't arguing, I was just asking a question - if according to some interpretation, there is no reality independent of observation, then what interpretation is given to predictions where no observation is possible? The answer could be "none", or it could be something else perhaps.